# Node canvas registerFont not working on server

Tags: javascript, linux, canvas, server, node-canvas

ı am working with nodejs 19.4 and canvas version is 2.11.2 my linux server equal with this versions. There is no error messege with my code but in local development ı can get the result as ı want but in the server ı can't apply the font ı want.
`registerFont('./Cormorant.tff', {family: 'Cormorant', style: 'normal'});`
I use this funcion before creating canvas context also ı have a problem with stroke style

```
canvasCtx.lineWidth = designTemplate.strokeWidth;
canvasCtx.strokeStyle = designTemplate.strokeColor;
canvasCtx.strokeText(data.line, data.x + Xadder, data.y);
```

Also this not causing any problem in my local development

in my server ı get this output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpDlI.png)

my local machine ı can get this output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spanz.png)

I install all requirements in documentaion
`apt-get install -y build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev`

Trying to works my application as ı did on my local machine